# How to solve $\left(cos\left(2x\right)\right)^{2cos\left(3x\right)+4cos\left(x\right)-1}=\frac{1}{cos\left(2x\right)}$

Tags: trigonometry

How to solve $\left(cos\left(2x\right)\right)^{2cos\left(3x\right)+4cos\left(x\right)-1}=\frac{1}{cos\left(2x\right)}$?

Here is what I've done: $$\left(cos\left(2x\right)\right)^{2cos\left(3x\right)+4cos\left(x\right)}=1,\ cos\left(2x\right)\neq0$$
**Case 1**
$$2cos\left(3x\right)+4cos\left(x\right)=0$$
$$4\left(cos\left(x\right)\right)^3-5cos\left(x\right)=0$$
$$cos\left(x\right)\left(4cos^2\left(x\right)-5\right)=0$$
$$cos\left(x\right)=0$$
$$x=\frac{\pi}{2}+k\pi$$
**Case 2**
$$cos\left(2x\right)=1$$
$$x=\frac{k\pi}{2}$$

Is there a 3rd case where $cos\left(x\right)=-1$ and $2cos\left(3x\right)+4cos\left(x\right)$ is even?

Comment: Sorry, I misread the problem, thus deleted my answer (which had a syntax issue anyway).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have

$cos(3x)=4cos^3(x)-3cos(x)$

so, your equation is

$(cos(2x))^{2cos(x)(4cos^2(x)-1)}=1$

with $cos(2x)\neq0$ or

$x\neq \frac{\pi}{4}+k\frac{\pi}{2}$.

FIRST CASE.

The exponent is zero.

this gives

$cos(x)=0$ and $x=\frac{\pi}{2}+k\pi$

or

$cos(x)=\frac{1}{2}=cos(\frac{\pi}{3})$ and

$x=\pm \frac{\pi}{3}+2k\pi$ or

$cos(x)=-\frac{1}{2}=cos(\frac{4\pi}{3})$

and

$x=\pm \frac{4\pi}{3}+2k\pi$.

SECOND CASE

if $cos(2x)=1$ then $x=k\pi$.

THIRD CASE

if $cos(2x)=-1$,  we will have

$2cos^2(x)-1=-1$ ,

which becomes $cos(x)=0$ and $x=\frac{\pi}{2}+k\pi$ and the equation is satisfied.

Finally, the solutions are:

$\frac{\pi}{2}+k\pi$,

$\pm \frac{\pi}{3}+2k\pi$,

$\pm \frac{4\pi}{3}+2k\pi$

and

$k\pi$.